# Skin depth at 50 Hz is much longer than the thickness of the shield of a coax cable. Then how does it work?

Tags: noise, electromagnetism, measurement, cables

The title already narrates the question.

We know that using a coax cable for audio amplifier input remarkably reduces 50 Hz noise. However the skin depth of the EM radiation at 50 Hz for copper is about 10mm (http://chemandy.com/calculators/skin-effect-calculator.htm).

Then how does it prevent 50 Hz EM wave from penetrating to the core?

Comment: I have no idea what the skin effect should have to do with shielding against emi here...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shielding on a coax cable doesn't "block" an interfering signal by absorbing it.  It works by conducting the interfering signal along its length to ground .  Thus, for the shield to work, it must present a low resistance to ground.

When you calculate this for high frequency signals, the results tell you that the currents flow along the outside of the shield, and not along the inside parts of the shield, and therefore the resistance might be higher and the part of the shield towards the inside is effectively being wasted.  When you calculate this for a 50 Hz signal, the results tell you that the entire thickness of the shield will be used to conduct away the interfering signal.

Answer (score 5):

Skin depth primarily doesn't apply because the interfering signal isn't primarily an EM wave; it's usually either an electric field (from nearby high voltages) or a magnetic field (from nearby high currents).

In the case of an electric field, the shield just needs to present a low impedance to ground along its full length, acting as a Faraday cage for the circuitry inside.

In the case of a magnetic field, screening is more difficult since the field will induce a definite voltage along the length of the shield : if it is connected at both ends, that voltage can drive hum in an earth loop; if it is not, as Dave Tweed points out in a comment, the same voltage is induced on the screen and the signal wires.

The screen may attenuate the magnetic field a little but won't eliminate it like a Faraday cage eliminates an electric field; where magnetic fields are the primary interference problem, iron or mu-metal shields are required to eliminate the field (by providing a low-reluctance path to conduct the magnetic flux around the signal), or balanced connections are used, where both legs pick up the same interfering signal which is cancelled out by a differential receiver.

Note that to effectively radiate and receive a true EM signal at 50Hz without deliberate inductors would require circuitry of size similar to a quarter-wave at 50Hz, and that's on a continental scale...

Comment: For magnetic fields, the voltage induced in the inner and outer conductors is exactly the same, since they have exactly the same axis of symmetry. Therefore, the interference is entirely common-mode. A coaxial cable does not *create* an external magnetic field for the same reason. Anything that disturbs the balance of current between the inner and outer conductors (e.g., additional ground paths) will reduce its ability to shield against magnetic fields.

Comment: [I'm aware of a continental-scale 50Hz circuit...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_distribution_network)